# QT frame visualisation

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Currently started to work with qt and found some bug in my code, and I can't understand where it comes from. Maybe you will see and explain why it happens.

Here is main.cpp code part which changes shutter from 3000 to maximum:

```
if (camera.test_cam->liveFrameReady())
        {
            camera.visualizeFrame(camera.test_cam->liveFrame());
            camera.set_shutter(0, 1, 3000 + i * 200);
            controlWidget->update(camera.test_cam->liveFrame());
            i++;
        }
```

The code works slowly(1 fps ), because of the camera.visuzlizeFrame() method:

```
void OsCam::visualizeFrame(Common::FrameHandle hFrame)
{
    void* buffer_ptr = this->getFrameData(hFrame);
    int width = hFrame->dataType()->width();
    int height = hFrame->dataType()->height();
    cv::Mat m(height, width, CV_8UC3, (int*)buffer_ptr);
    cv::imshow("test image", m);
    cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

Gui interface shows the camera frame in real time, test image from visualizeFrame at the background

[image]

Actionally, I don't need to call this method (I used it just to be sure that I can read the memory and I used opencv because I am more familiar with it).

But if I get rid of this camera.visuzlizeFrame() my gui becomes white and does not give any response.
Even if I use cv::waitKey or Sleep functions, nothing happens to the gui.

```
void ControlWidget::update(Common::FrameHandle hFrame)
{
    try
    {
        QImage img((uchar*)hFrame->buffer()->data(), hFrame->dataType()->width(), hFrame->dataType()->height(), QImage::Format::Format_RGB888);
        QSize standart_size = QSize(hFrame->dataType()->width() / 3, hFrame->dataType()->height() / 3);
        QPixmap rectPxmp = QPixmap::fromImage(img).scaled(standart_size);
        this->camera_1->setPixmap(rectPxmp);
        this->camera_2->setPixmap(rectPxmp);
        cv::waitKey(300);
    }

    catch (GeneralException& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Shall I go to QThreads? One thread for reading the buffer and another one for visualization of gui?
Thank you!

some additional code:

```
void* OsCam::getFrameData(Common::FrameHandle hFrame)
{
    bool displayFrameData = false;
    void* pFrameData = NULL;
    try
    {
        if (hFrame)
        {
            if (displayFrameData)
            {
                // display information about the frame
                cout << "Frame index: " << hFrame->frameIndex();
                cout << "Frame timestamp: " << hFrame->timestamp();
                // display information about the frame "data type"
                DataTypeHandle hDataType = hFrame->dataType();
                cout << "Frame size in bytes: " << hDataType->frameSizeInBytes() << endl;
                cout << "Width in pixels: " << DataType::width(hDataType) << endl;
                cout << "Height in rows: " << DataType::height(hDataType) << endl;
                cout << "Bit depth: " << DataType::bitDepth(hDataType) << endl;
                cout << "Bytes/line (stride): " << DataType::stride(hDataType) << endl;
                // display the frame video format
                VideoDataType::Format videoFormat = VideoDataType::format(hDataType);
                cout << "Video format: " << VideoDataType::formatString(videoFormat).c_str() << endl;
                // get a pointer to the frame data
            }
            pFrameData = hFrame->buffer()->data();
        }
    }
    catch (GeneralException& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return pFrameData;
}
```

and main (I changed it a little bit) :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ControlWidget *controlWidget = new ControlWidget;
    //controlWidget->show();

    try
    {

        OsCam camera;
        int i = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j<10000 ; j++)
        {
            if ((camera.test_cam->liveFrameReady()))
            {
                Common::FrameHandle loaded = camera.test_cam->liveFrame()->clone();
                camera.visualizeFrame(loaded);
                controlWidget->update(loaded);
                camera.set_shutter(0, 1, 3000 + i * 200);
                loaded->~Frame();
            }
            i++;
        }


    }
    catch (GeneralException& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        int a;
        std::cin >> a;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

After cv::named_window

[image]

Comment: can output the maximum shutter (or the final `i`)?

Comment: the final I is less then 100. I am afraid I read and write memory in the same time, or  I might don't have any idle time, and that's why the processor reads and processes the image, so there is no time for visualisation

Comment: the waitKey(300) combined with the shutter of 100 will result in about 2 fps.Can you try to change waitKey(300) to waitKey(1)?

Comment: the shutter is in e-10-6 (microseconds)

Comment: ok, then wairKey(300) will result in about 3 fps...

Comment: So I want to point that it's not about fps. Its the strange thing if i call visualizeFrame method - i can see a gui normally, but if I dont, gui is just white

Comment: some Qt gui? Or the opencv gui window? Can you add gui screenshots?

Comment: qt gui. I added the screenshot link (cant add images, because I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: can you add code of OsCam::getFrameData()? Where (or when, if from a signal) is visualizeFrame() called? Where or when is ControlWidget::update called?

Comment: if you add cv::namedWindow to ControlWidget::update, does your gui work?

Comment: update is called from main, in the main thread.  I will add the code in a second

Comment: Micka: 
if you add cv::namedWindow to ControlWidget::update, does your gui work?  
Answer: Yes it works. Screenshot attached to the question/

Comment: Qt has an event loop, any gui update etc. will happen during that event loop, so during for (int j = 0; j<10000 ; j++) no gui action can be performed unless you explicitly give Qt the chance to use some time in the event loop. In the past there was a method to call during your loop, but I'm not sure whether it still exists. The right way to do it is to move all the user stuff from your main to a Qt slot and activate that slot from a signal (e.g. clicked a button)